# Pattern in new iPhone UDID format

Tags: ios, iphone

Previously iPhone UDID was 40 characters. Now for iPhone Xs, Xr, Xs Max, they change to 20 characters with hyphen. It looks like it is following some sort of pattern. Does anyone know anything about it?

We have several Xs and they all start with `00008020-`

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. Perhaps you should post this at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5):

Apple has changed UDIDs for the new devices so they are not always 40 characters long anymore. They can be either shorter, or longer than 40 characters. This has already caused some issues for MDM vendors that relied on UDIDs to be 40 characters, for example VMWare:

[VMWare AirWatch support article](https://support.workspaceone.com/articles/360009077393-Update-Compatibility-patch-for-upcoming-Apple-devices)